# Help ! Error -13 trying to connect my local files to remix Ide

Tags: solidity, remix

Hi i am trying to setup work environment by connecting local files to remix ide

i keep getting this error when i run code

remixd -s "absolute url path" --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org

and the output `[Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@remix-project/remixd/origins.json'] { errno: -13, code: 'EACCES', syscall: 'open', path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@remix-project/remixd/origins.json' } [WARN] You may now only use IDE at https://remix.ethereum.org to connect to that instance [WARN] Any application that runs on your computer can potentially read from and write to all files in the directory. [WARN] Symbolic links are not forwarded to Remix IDE`

Comment: Hi there. Have you tried running the command with `sudo`?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks yes i have still no dice, it looks like a permission issue though

Answer (score 0):

Check your remix url : https://remix.ethereum.org instead of http://remix.ethereum.org